# Python subprocess Popen hangs before processing all commands

Tags: python, ipython, mpi, jupyter-notebook

Here is my initial problem/observation from a Jupyter Notebook `%%bash` magics cell that reproduces also in IPython console. I am intending to launch several MPI programs from Notebooks pages. Here, I use the `date` system command as a simple reproducer.

```
In [1]: %%bash
   ...: echo "First"
   ...: mpirun -np 2 date
   ...: echo "Second"
   ...: mpirun -np 2 date
   ...: echo "End"
   ...: 
First
mar. juin 27 15:17:36 CEST 2017
mar. juin 27 15:17:36 CEST 2017
```

Only the first `mpirun` command is execute, everything after is not executed. This behavior reproduces directly with `subprocess.Popen`, see the sample code below:

```
from subprocess import *
from IPython.utils import py3compat
def test(s):
    p = Popen(['bash'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate(s.encode('utf8', 'replace'))
    print(py3compat.bytes_to_str(out))
test("""echo "First"
mpirun -np 2 date
echo "Second"
mpirun -np 2 date
echo "End" """)
```

I am probably missing something but `Popen` seems to stop executing every command after the first `mpirun`. I get the expected result when everything is placed on a single line, but it is not really interesting for an IPython magic cell:

```
test("""echo "First"; mpirun -np 2 date; echo "Second";mpirun -np 2 date; echo "End" """)
```

Any ideas for the reason why `Popen` hangs ?
Thanks for feedback.

(Tested on Linux, using Python-2.7.13 with IPython-5.4.1 and also using Python 3.6.1 with IPython 6.1.0 and using several versions of OpenMPI-1.10.x and 2.1.x)

Comment: I'm utilizing Python 3.6.1 and iPython 6.1.0 and I don't have that problem.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78dut.png

 
I'm utilizing Python 3.6.1 and iPython 6.1.0 and I don't have that problem. enter image description here

I see that you change Python versions and iPython versions. You may have some setting in your bash that is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need bash for anything other than a shell? Can you use the shell=True Popen option and pass your string of commands directly to Popen? Works that way for me:

```
commands = """mpirun -np 2 date
mpirun -np 2 date
mpirun -np 2 date"""
p = Popen(commands, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p.stdout.read()
'Thu Jun 29 00:41:16 UTC 2017\nThu Jun 29 00:41:16 UTC 2017\nThu Jun 29 00:41:16 UTC 2017\nThu Jun 29 00:41:16 UTC 2017\nThu Jun 29 00:41:16 UTC 2017\nThu Jun 29 00:41:16 UTC 2017\n'
```